# How to remove halogen bulb from protective glass?

Tags: bulb, halogen

I have two of these sidelights with RS7 Linear Halogen Bulbs. They are encased in protective glass. Does anyone know how to get the bulb so I can replace please.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

This website won't let me upload the photos, so I have added them here...

https://twitter.com/BonfireHeart17/status/1353015669575581696?s=19

Comment: I have had those before I am thinking the clips have been bent over, mine snapped in place.  I would try prying one side up.

Answer (score 1):

Pull those two metal tabs on each side of the glass straight out at the same time. The protective glass should pull off. Then grab the bulb in the center and move it a little to the right or left and pull out. The terminals are spring loaded. Install the new bulbs by inserting one end into the fixture, pushing in slightly and inserting the other end into the other side. Use a cloth to handle the bulb so you don't get body oil on it, that will decrease the life of the bulb. Put the protective glass back on and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you, was hard but that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have had those before I am thinking the clips have been bent over, mine snapped in place.  I would try prying one side up. They also make LED versions, of those lamps not as hot and they don't need the explosion shield. (I believe all open globe lamps are required to have the shield incase the lamp explodes)
Make sure to Handel the new lamp with the packaging or a napkin , Kleenex without moisturizer, body oils on the lamp can cause them to explode.

Comment: Thank you that worked!